# bootstrap-table: Change default sorting first time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sorting, bootstrap-table

The first time I click on any sortable column, it sorts by 'asc'. How can I change it to 'desc'?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table" data-toggle="table">
   <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>first</td> <td>5.4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>second</td><td>7.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>third</td><td>2.1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `data-order='desc'` to your `<th>`, and you'll be good to go:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table" data-toggle="table">
   <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-order='desc' data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                <th data-order='desc' data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                <th data-order='desc' data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>first</td> <td>5.4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>second</td><td>7.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>third</td><td>2.1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is this using jquery ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the order you want it sorted.  Try adding:

```
data-sort-order="desc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add what is the default order Colum when initializing the BT table in JS. It used an index of colums. It was the order when you change the order. If you do not need to change order after that change parameter "bFilter" as false.

```js
    
    Table = $('#survey-table').DataTable({
        "order": [[3, "asc"]],
        "lengthChange": false,
        "info": true,
        "unique": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name" },
            { "data": "Level" },
            { "data": "Start Date" },
            { "data": "End Date" },
            { "data": "Status" },
            { "data": "Action" }
        ],
    });
```

OR-
If you only HTML you can default order like this.

```html
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-sort-name="id"
  data-sort-order="desc"
  data-height="460"
  data-url="json/data1.json">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```